# Segment Table Calculations

Tags: operating-system, radix, segments, register-allocation

I have a question. I "Googled" it many times but could not find the solution or any method to solve it.

> On a system using simple segmentation, the segment table is as follows (All values are in decimal):
>
> ```
> | Segment | Base Register Value | Limit Register Value |
> |---------|---------------------|----------------------|
> | 0       | 3000                | 1024                 |
> | 1       | 8192                | 1208                 |
> | 2       | 1000                | 1200                 |
> | 3       | 5000                | 2048                 |
> ```
>
> a) Draw a memory allocation chart showing all segments.
>
> b) Compute the physical addresses corresponding to the following segment+offset logical addresses (if the address generates a fault, indicate): `0+1200`, `1+500`, `3+1024`.
>
> c) Compute the logical segment+offset addresses corresponding to the following physical addresses (if the address generates a fault, indicate): `9000`, `50`, `1200`.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I added it as a picture. Couldn't you see?

Comment: Okay, i added it as text too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the answers; I think you will understand by taking a careful look at them:

a)

```
| Main Memory |              |
|-------------|--------------|
| 0           |              |
|             | Segment 2    |
| 1000        |              |
|             | unallocated  |
| 2200        |              |
|             | unallocated  |
| 3000        |              |
|             | Segment 0    |
| 4024        |              |
|             | unallocated  |
| 5000        |              |
|             | Segment 3    |
| 7048        |              |
|             | unallocated  |
| 8192        |              |
|             | Segment 1    |
| 9208        |              |
| ...         | unallocated  |
```

b) `0+1200 --> 4200`, `1+500 --> 8692`, `3+1024 --> 6024`.

c) `9000 --> 1+808`, `50 --> fault`, `1200 --> 2+200`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understand how can i do